# Operating system ejectable SSD

Tags: ssd, operating-systems

Why is my SSD, on which my operating system (Windows 7) is installed, showing as an ejectable device? I tried to eject it, half-expecting the drive to burst out of my case, but the device was - obviously - in use:

[image]

My other two mechanical hard drives are not on the list, and the SSD works fine otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SATA drives often show up as eject-able because the SATA protocol permits hot disconnection and reconnection of drives, and because Windows doesn't know what SATA ports are connected to internal drives and what ones are used for external (eSATA) drives.

[See how to disable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463521.aspx)

Comment: Now your link gets redirected to _"Windows Hardware Dev Center Archive"_, so the article you referred to got archived. This is a good example why you have to copy the relevant parts of the linked article into your own post, not just paste a link, and see what happens in the future...
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
_"Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."_